# Foolproof way of getting output encoding?

Tags: python, character-encoding, stdout

I thought that `sys.stdout.encoding` would be the definitive way of knowing the encoding used by `print`, but that is demonstrably false:

```
>>> hello_in_chinese = '\u4f60\u597d'
>>> print(sys.stdout.encoding, hello_in_chinese)
cp1252 你好
>>> hello_in_chinese.encode(sys.stdout.encoding)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#65>", line 1, in <module>
    hello_in_chinese.encode(sys.stdout.encoding)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: character maps to <undefined>
```

This was in IDLE under Python 3.6.3, on Windows 7.

How can you get the encoding that's actually being used?

Comment: My knowledge of encodings and terminals admittedly isn't the best, but how does printing a string prove that it's not using a certain encoding? You'll get the exact same output with the code `sys.stdout.buffer.write('\u4f60\u597d\n'.encode(sys.stdout.encoding))`, no?

Comment: @Aran-Fey cp1252 doesn't have any chinese characters in it.

Comment: Ah, makes sense now.

Comment: @Aran-Fey thanks to your comment I realize I didn't explain myself well enough, so I updated the example.